# Android View initialize and display problems

Tags: android, view, fadein, floating-action-button

I try to display a "custom" view when FloatingButton is pressed, but something gone wrong with the view (like Google Agenda when you tap on the FloatingButton, such as a "fade in" view).
This is my view (it is located between the a ViewPager and the Fab buttons):

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/shadowView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

This is the method:

```
public void animateFAB() {

    if (isFabOpen) {

        //animation classic 1
        fabNormal.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
        fabShare.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fabFavorit.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fabShare.setClickable(false);
        fabFavorit.setClickable(false);
        isFabOpen = false;
        mShadowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    } else {
        //animation classic 1
        fabNormal.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        fabShare.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fabFavorit.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fabShare.setClickable(true);
        fabFavorit.setClickable(true);
        isFabOpen = true;
        mShadowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

And this is the problem:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

Well I didn't find any solution of this problem, someone can help me?

thanks

Comment: Where do you initialize your view?

Comment: Inside onCreate method of the class, I just do like:

View mShadowView = (View) findViewById(R.id.shadowView);

Comment: And is your view in the same xml file that you use in `setContentView()`?

Comment: yes, the shadowView is inside the same view of the setContentView().

Comment: Two suggestions: 
1) You're calling animateFAB() before assigning mShadowView. 
2) You're actually calling "View mShadowView = (View) findViewById(R.id.shadowView);" -> not assigning member of a class, but only a local variable in onCreate().

Comment: Mmmm...ok well, the method is called after the assigning of mShadowView, for the second one who I can use the "custom view" on the xml if I don't assign it? @RomanKolomenskii

Comment: Ok, so I find the problem: I just put the assignment in the wrong place...

Comment: if you figure out what was wrong, it is prudent to answer your own question with the solution (to help others) and accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is the solution:

```
mShadowView = findViewById(R.id.shadowView);

fabShare.setOnClickListener(this);
fabFavorit.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I just put the declaration of the View before the setOnClickListener